# How to create a raw link in view(with contexual filter) custom text

Tags: views

I am creating a block in view.
I have a content type with a field(plain text).
I am passing contexual filter "content id" from url.

I am giving value in the fields as "www.facebook.com/SomePage"
Now i want that to be created as link text from custom text in views.

In custom text i am providing

```
    <a href="{{ field_abc }}" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

Now when i click here it is redirecting me to "[sitename]/node/www.facebook.com/SomePage"

I want to open like www.facebook.com/SomePage.

How to do.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather add a 'Custom text' field to the view, give it some text ("Click here"), and under "Rewrite Results" check "Output this field as a custom link", link path is `{{ field_abc }}` and then check "External server URL"